# How to remove a duplicate element from a file path stored in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I just started as an intern at an unnamed large compnay. I am trying to make a program that scrapes a folder and stores the file paths then returns the file paths as individual elements to be passed down later to be used in a function. I am sure the issue is with duplicate \\ added to the file paths, but what is the best way to remove them? The program will be running through 10,000+ files so optimization is necessary. The code is not currently opening the files but is working all the way through path_array

```
     #Run the above function and store its results in a variable.   
     full_file_paths = get_filepaths(r'C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Test')

     #splitting the filepath list to be able to cycle  
     paths = str(full_file_paths)
     split_list = paths.split(',')
     print("This is the split list")
     print(split_list)
     print(len(split_list))

     path_array = np.array_split(split_list,len(split_list))

     # File path to be opened
     path = path_array[0]

     # flags
     flags = os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT


     # Open the specified file path
     # using os.open() method
     # and get the file descriptor for 
     # opened file path
     fd = os.open(path, flags)

     print("File path opened successfully.")
```

Comment: What does `get_filepaths` give you and why do you have to convert it to a `str`?  What happens if there's a comma in a path?

Comment: \\ Makes no difference in a file path, it will be treated as a single \